# Unprotect Method of Worksheet class failed (Only on more than one sheet)

Tags: vba, excel

So I am trying to fix some old code in an Excel workbook that my company provided. The goal is to print out a certain section of every worksheet (Using a print-all "button"), but for some reason I keep getting an error that states that I cannot unprotect the workbook.

One weird quirk is that this only occurs when there is more than one page to print. With one page it works just fine.

```
        Worksheets(ws.name).Select (False)
        With Worksheets(ws.name).PageSetup
            .PrintTitleRows = ""
            .PrintTitleColumns = ""
        End With

        Worksheets(ws.name).Unprotect
        'ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        Worksheets(ws.name).PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:l" & ActiveSheet.Range("B10").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 10
```

Edit: When I add a blank password to the Unprotect line, it will go to the next line

```
Worksheets(ws.name).PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:l" & ActiveSheet.Range("B10").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 10
```

where I get an error saying that I cannot use this command on a protected sheet

Comment: For the sheet you're trying to unprotect, can you unprotect it manually with a blank password?

Comment: Does `...Select (False)` do something? I've never seen that, just curious.  If `ws` is a worksheet, you could just use `ws.Unprotect`, etc.  If it goes to the next line with a blank password, does it not unprotect the sheet?

Comment: I have no idea what the Select (False) does. This is old code from a document that a former employee wrote. I have had a nightmare trying to fix what the old employee wrote as literally everything was broken to some degree.

Comment: "When I add a blank password to the Unprotect line, it will go to the next line"--- Debug the code manually by pressing F8 key and once the unprotect line is executed, check if the sheet is really unprotected.

Comment: The False argument causes to select both the worksheet stored in variable ws AND the active worksheet, thus grouping two sheets if a worksheet other than ws was selected when the code is run. The code is very messy indeed.